# AWS Cloudformation: Network Share Drive is inaccessible in cfn-init or UserData

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to copy files from a network share drive upon launching the EC2 instance in cloudformation:

```
Resources:
     MigrationInstance:
        Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
        Properties:
          ...
          UserData:
            Fn::Base64: !Sub |
              <powershell>
              New-Item "C:\migratedFiles" -itemType Directory

              #Copy-Item -Path \\192.168.41.103\shared\* -Destination C:\migratedFiles -Recurse -Force # also don't work

              cfn-init.exe --verbose --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource MigrationInstance --region ${AWS::Region}
              </powershell>
              <persist>true</persist>
        Metadata: 
          AWS::CloudFormation::Init: 
            config:
              files:
                C:\windows\temp\copyfiles.ps1:
                  content: !Sub |
                    $sourcePathExist = Test-Path \\192.168.41.103\shared
                    if($sourcePathExist) #this is always false
                    {
                      # Copy-Item -Path \\192.168.41.103\shared\* -Destination C:\migratedFiles -Recurse -Force
                      xcopy \\192.168.41.103\shared C:\migratedFiles /E /H /C /I
                      
                      Write-Output "Migrate files success"
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Write-Warning "Migrate files failed"
                    }
                    
              commands:
                1-RunCopyFiles:
                  command:
                    powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "C:\windows\temp\copyfiles.ps1"
                  waitAfterCompletion: 'forever'
```

But it seems like the shared folder is not accessible in `cfn-init` as `Test-Path \\192.168.41.103\shared` returns `false`..

But when I manually run the `Test-Path` in the EC2 instance - it returns `true` and the `xcopy` command works

`xcopy \\192.168.41.103\shared C:\migratedFiles /E /H /C /I`

It seems to me that the shared drive is not accessible in `UserData` and `cfn-init`. But it is accessible when you SSM into the instance and manually run the command there (the `xcopy` works and the `test-path` returns `true`). I wonder why is this the case?

Comment: Sounds about right, user-data script is run after the instance has been launched. But I don't quite understand what you mean when you say "not accessible in UserData and cfn-init".

Comment: @ChristophFischer basically the `xcopy` script is failing because it can't access `\\192.168.41.103\shared` and `Test-Path`'ing this directory is returning `false`.. where in if i connect to the Ec2 instance and run the same `xcopy` script it is working and the `Test-Path` is returning `true`.. so it seems to me it can't access the shared drive in `UserData/cfn-init` in cloudformation but manually if you `ssm` into the instance and run the same exact command it works... which is really puzzling...

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the instance need to be joined to the AD domain. But still confusing why I can access it from Ec2 manually even if its not domain joined.